# Marshalling an unknown Array size

Tags: c#, arrays, size, marshalling

You have a structure that takes a byte array

```
byte[]
```

however, the size of that array depends on the image you are submitting (widthxheight)

So... how do you do

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ???)]
public Byte[] ImageData;
```

Is the sizeconst a MUST HAVE when working with byte arrays being passed from C# to C dlls?

Comment: A custom marshaller seems like the only choice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the marshalling type.  SizeConst is required if you're marshalling as ByValArray, but not with other types.  For details, look at the [UnmanagedType enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx).

My suspicion is that you want to marshall as a C pointer to the array:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
```

This will cause it to marshall through to a standard C array (BYTE*), so only a pointer is passed through.  Doing this allows you to pass any sized array.  Typically, you'll also want to pass through the array size as another parameter (or image width/height/bpp, which provides the same info), since there's no way in C/C++ to tell that easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Reed.  However, I did that and now get this error

    Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination  (Arrays fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray)

When building the IntPtr and then Marshal.StructureToPtr...  Thoughts?

Comment: Check out the enum.  There would be more information required.  I was assuming you were marshalling from managed -> unmanaged, but if you're going the other way around, you can either Marhsal it as an IntPtr (instead of a byte[]) or set it up to use a SafeArray.

Comment: Unfortunately using anything but [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ArrayByVal, sizeConst = xxxx)] messes up the memory addressing. So essentially there's a struct (which contains a byte[]) that needs to be converted to an IntPtr so it can be passed to the DLL. And the data in the byte[] is getting messed up.  Verified this by copying the data from the IntPtr to a byte[] and looking at the data to find that everything is changed unless I've set the MarshalAs in the struct.

Comment: @Olewolfe same thing is happening to me with a double array.  I am using PInvoke from managed to unmanaged.  My double array is also inside a struct.  According [to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7(v=vs.110).aspx), One-dimensional arrays of blittable types, [are themselves blittable]. **However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable**.  I think what this means is that your byte array itself is considered blittable but as soon as you put the array in a struct, the struct looses its blittable-ness.

Comment: According to [this article](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/passing-managed-structures-with-arrays-to-unmanaged-code-part-1/) the way to get around this is to use a SAFEARRAY.